# cannot start PowerPC guest - QEMU/KVM

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, powerpc

i'm having a lot of trouble starting up my PPC virtual machine. the returned error code is `qemu-system-ppc64: Expected key=value format, found hv_relaxed`, and i'm not sure what can i do about it. it doesn't inform me about any CPU issues, which it tended to do if i left the settings at default, so i would like to know a potential solution. i use QEMU/KVM 4.2.0 with libvirtd on Linux Mint 20 (Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa).

Comment: Can you post your qemu command line or libvirt xml file?

Comment: forget about it, it seems to be a Debian-specific issue